# How to recognize current activity of user from a service?

Tags: android, service, activity-recognition

I have tried to make a service to recognize the user's current activity.
But this code crashes everytime.

It throws exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.location.DetectedActivity com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult.getMostProbableActivity()' on a null object reference
at com.always_in_beta.ecodrive.service.UserTrackService.detectActivity(UserTrackService.java:51)
at com.always_in_beta.ecodrive.service.UserTrackService$1.run(UserTrackService.java:27)

The code is:

```
public class UserTrackService extends Service {

    public Handler handler = null;
    public Runnable runnable = null;
    int count = 0;
    public Context context = this;
    public Intent intentt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                detectActivity();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 4000);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        intentt = intent;
        return null;
    }

    public void detectActivity() {
        ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intentt);
        DetectedActivity activity = result.getMostProbableActivity();
        Toast.makeText(context, activity.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("tag_tag_tag", activity.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ActivityRecognitionResult#extractResult(android.content.Intent)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionResult.html#extractResult(android.content.Intent))

> **Returns**
>   an ActivityRecognitionResult, or null if the intent doesn't
>   contain an ActivityRecognitionResult.

So, according to your null pointer stacktrace, that's expected because you can't run `getMostProbableActivity()` on a **null**.

Comment: I want to detect the activity of the user on a regular interval, but am unable to implement. Can you please tell me where to start?

Comment: @user10445346 did you find a solution?